# Consider that & Consideration(s) that

Tags: grammaticality, usage

[According to Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/consider)

> **consider (that)** to think of someone or something in a particular way or to have a particular opinion : *The local authority considered that the school did not meet requirements*.

In that example sentence from Longman, could we use *considerations that* instead of *consider that*?

> *The local authority based its decision **on consideration that** the school did not meet requirements.*

Comment: I don't think you can they can base their actions on considerations. They can 'take into consideration that...' and then decide or 'consider that...' before any action is taken.

Comment: I think you can use it then. I found several examples of the same usages of 'considerations that...' in the British National Corpus. I'll post it in an answer.

Comment: @Sander, please delete your answer! I want to delete the question.Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to delete the question? It might be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can, but you'd need to add an article before the word *consideration*:

> *The local authority based its decision on **a** consideration that the school did not meet requirements*.

The example sentence from Longman isn't the easiest to follow, but here's how I'd interpret your sentence:

- A local authority (perhaps a school board?) made a ruling (a.k.a. a *decision*)
- The decision (fire the school's principal, perhaps?) was made after a *consideration* (NOAD defines *consideration* as *a fact or a motive taken into account in deciding or judging something*, so the word fits here).
- What was this "fact or motive"? *The school was not meeting requirements*. We don't know what those unmet requirements were, but, if this were a news article, I would hope the journalist would elaborate on that in subsequent sentences, or in the next paragraph.

Comment: Now I am convinced that that structure is correct and acceptable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. After a search in the British National Corpus, I found several instances with the same usage of *consideration that...* followed by a sentence with a subject or object other than the *consideration* itself. Here are a few of them:

> - The difference was compounded even further with the **consideration that** American pay-rates were two or three times ours.
> - Hailey's reservations about Indirect Rule were *based* purely *upon* **the** practical **consideration that** in its dogmatic insistence on working only through the authentic traditional leadership it excluded other, possibly more effective, methods of securing the essential ‘degree of acquiescence’ in British rule.

However, the usage of *considerations that* (the plural) seems to be slightly different, so I would use the singular form in your sentence.

Comment: This is where I got it from: http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=consideration+that&mysubmit=Go

Comment: -1 because I think your first sentence is incorrect. The main verb in OP's text is ***to base***, which in this context *must* be transitive *(the authority based **its decision** [on something])*. Disregarding the matter of singular/plural, ***on consideration[s] that [blah blah]*** is an adverbial modifier - it can't serve as the grammatical *object* for *to base*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why not? NOAD defines _consideration_ as "a fact or a motive taken into account in deciding or judging something". With that definition, I'm having trouble following your argument that a _consideration_ "can't serve as the grammatical object for _to base_".

Comment: @J.R.: I'll cancel my downvote, because on reflection my argument above probably doesn't hold up. But I note there are dozens of instances of [*based its decision on consideration **of***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22based+its+decision+on+consideration+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *[something taken into consideration]* for both singular and plural *considerations*, whereas there are none at all for *...consideration **that** [some fact applies]*. I may not know the grammatical justification, but I know what I don't like - and apparently nor do others like OP's usage.